# WebGl animation appearing only when mouse enter into the screen

Tags: canvas, webgl, three.js

I'm making my first animation with WebGL and three.js. Everything goes well except that my animation only appears when the mouse has entered the window.

[My animation](http://wabeo.fr?theme=auriga-7)

My code :

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var wi       = window.innerWidth;
var he       = window.innerHeight;
var renderer  = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
var scene    = new THREE.Scene();
var camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,wi/he,1,10000);
var distance = 500;
var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();

renderer.setSize(wi ,he);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(camera);

var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '/wp-content/themes/auriga-7/i/cloud.png' );
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture,transparent: true} );
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 400,400,4,8 );


for ( ix = 0; ix <100; ix++ ) {
item = new THREE.Mesh( plane, material );
item.position.x = ((Math.random()-0.5)*(Math.random() * wi/2) /4)*Math.random()*10;
item.position.y = ((Math.random()-0.5)*(Math.random() * he/2) /4)*Math.random()*10;
item.position.z = ix*10-50;
item.rotation.z = Math.random() *250;
item.scale.x = item.scale.y = Math.random() * Math.random() * 2 + 0.5;

THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry2,item);
}

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
scene.add(mesh);


camera.position.z = distance;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
renderer.sortObjects = false;


// create a point light
var pointLight =
  new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);

// set its position
pointLight.position.x = 10;
pointLight.position.y = 50;
pointLight.position.z = 130;

// add to the scene
scene.add(pointLight);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

document.addEventListener('mousemove',onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('resize',onResizeMyFuckinBrowser,false);
function onMouseMove(event){

var mouseX = event.clientX - wi/2;
var mouseY = event.clientY - he/2;

camera.position.x = (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.02;
camera.position.y = (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.02;
camera.position.z = distance;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
function onResizeMyFuckinBrowser(){
var wi       = window.innerWidth;
var he       = window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize(wi ,he);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture loading is an asynchronous event. Most likely, your `render()` call in the main program occurs before the texture has loaded. Your other `render()` calls only occur on mouse move events and resize events. This is why you see nothing until the mouse is moved.

If you don't want to use `requestAnimationFrame()`, you can look at the arguments of `ImageUtils.loadTexture()`, where you will see an option for a callback function. You could place a render call inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks !!

I juste change the line you said by :

`var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '/wp-content/themes/auriga-7/i/cloud.png',{}, renderer.render(scene, camera);`

... and it work perfectly now !